# Change product increment value for attribute

Tags: javascript, attributes, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

Prestashop v1.6.1.13 default-bootstrap theme.

When I change in product.js

```
// The button to increment the product value
$(document).on('click', '.product_quantity_up', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    fieldName = $(this).data('field-qty');
    var currentVal = parseInt($('input[name='+fieldName+']').val());
    if (!allowBuyWhenOutOfStock && quantityAvailable > 0)
        quantityAvailableT = quantityAvailable;
    else
        quantityAvailableT = 100000000;
    if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal < quantityAvailableT)
        $('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(currentVal + 1).trigger('keyup');
    else
        $('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(quantityAvailableT);
    $('#quantity_wanted').change();
});
```

to this:

```
// The button to increment the product value
$(document).on('click', '.product_quantity_up', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    fieldName = $(this).data('field-qty');
    var currentVal = parseInt($('input[name='+fieldName+']').val());
    if (!allowBuyWhenOutOfStock && quantityAvailable > 0)
    quantityAvailableT = quantityAvailable;
    else
        quantityAvailableT = 100000000;
    if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal < quantityAvailableT)
        $('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(currentVal + 2).trigger('keyup'); //this line changed
    else
        $('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(quantityAvailableT);
    $('#quantity_wanted').change();
});
```

I'm able to change value in input for 2 qauntity up on every time when I push increment button, but when I put in code `minimalQuantity` and code looks like: `$('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(currentVal + minimalQuantity).trigger('keyup');` this is work only for product witout attributes. If product have attributes this is didnt work, it seems like `minimalQuantity` for product without attributes give correct value but for product with attributes value is always 1. How I can fix it?

Comment: Where is declared your **minimalQuantity** variable? And how do you define a product with/without attributes?

Comment: In product attribute combination is option to set value for `minimalQuantity` below this code from topic in product.js is `if (typeof minimalQuantity != 'undefined' && minimalQuantity)
 {
  checkMinimalQuantity();
  $(document).on('keyup', 'input[name=qty]', function(e){
   checkMinimalQuantity(minimalQuantity);
  });
 }`

Comment: I'm still confused, could you add a jsfiddle or a snippet here?

Comment: I can't because this is part of biggest code in PrestaShop. Ib back office merchant can set minimalQuantity for regular product and for attributes of product too. If we do that we can use `minimalQuantity` in product.js but this is work only for regular product without attributes, and I don't know why. I think this question is only for people who know how works PrestaShop 1.6.

Answer (score 0):

On product page you have a global JS variable `combinations` that stores all info about combinations. It gets included into DOM so you can search for it there.

Example of variable:

```
var combinations = 
{
  "31": {
    "attributes_values": {
      "1": "S",
      "3": "Yellow"
    },
    "attributes": [
      1,
      16
    ],
    "price": 0,
    "specific_price": false,
    "ecotax": 0,
    "weight": 0,
    "quantity": 300,
    "reference": "",
    "unit_impact": 0,
    "minimal_quantity": "1",
    "date_formatted": "",
    "available_date": "",
    "id_image": 16,
    "list": "'1','16'"
  },
  ...
}
```

So you need to get `minimal_quantity` variable inside the object of selected combination id from the list above.

```
// The button to increment the product value
$(document).on('click', '.product_quantity_up', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    fieldName = $(this).data('field-qty');
    var curCombinationId = $('#idCombination').val();
    var minCombinationQty = minimalQuantity; // set default product minimal quantity
    if (combinations != 'undefined') { // check if product has combinations
        for (var combData in combinations) {
            if (combData.idCombination == curCombinationId) {
                minCombinationQty = parseInt(combData.minimal_quantity);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    var currentVal = parseInt($('input[name='+fieldName+']').val());
    if (!allowBuyWhenOutOfStock && quantityAvailable > 0)
        quantityAvailableT = quantityAvailable;
    else
        quantityAvailableT = 100000000;
    if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal < quantityAvailableT)
        $('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(currentVal + minCombinationQty).trigger('keyup');
    else
        $('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(quantityAvailableT);

    $('#quantity_wanted').change();
});
```

Comment: When I use in product.js: console.log(combination) in source code I see correct value for minimal_quantity for this combination of attributes but still I dont know how I can use it for this product and regular product in product.js?

Comment: Thanks for update, I just check this code and this is not working for me. Maybe I had to put this code in specific place in product.js?

Comment: @AgnesTom "this is not working" doesn't tell me anything. Do you get an error in console? Are you using this code before `$('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(currentVal + minimalQuantity).trigger('keyup');` and you changed it to `$('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(currentVal + minCombinationQty).trigger('keyup');`?

Comment: Now my code looks like: https://jsfiddle.net/s3ss1e65/ when I try increment product with attribute input is red color and blank, product without attribute increment button didn't work just redirect to top of page.

Comment: @AgnesTom No you need to put the code inside `$(document).on('click', '.product_quantity_up', function(e)` function... obviously.

Comment: Now my code is https://jsfiddle.net/s3ss1e65/1/ in normall product in console I have this error: Uncaught ReferenceError: combinations is not defined and increment button didn't wor, for product with attributes there is no error but button increment only +1 it supposed icrement +3.

Comment: @AgnesTom On normal product you get error because there are no combinations and with product attributes it doesn't increment properly because the `minimal_quantity` value is string. I updated the answer with the code. Also make sure you have enough quantity available, otherwise when you add quantity it will set to max quantity available.

Comment: Still the same as previous, for try I moved two }} from `if` and `for` loop and put it above `$('#quantity_wanted').change();` now in product with attribute increment is not +3 but +6 so it doubled value :-/

Comment: @AgnesTom Is your website live somewhere to see the problem?

Comment: I edit your answer and put there correct code, I want edit my topic but I click in wrong place :)  Please accept change and I will mark it as solved.

Comment: @AgnesTom Well you figured it out by yourself so you can post your own answer and mark it as solved.